# Highcharts start from left most corner without the gap

Tags: highcharts

I want my chart to start from left most corner from zero and without the gap. Please help me to out on this.
Here is my chart: http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/egQH8/2/

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            min: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100, startOnTick: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 0, 0, 0, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });
});
```

Here is the screen shot of what I'm talking about:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c347ofz76

Answer (score 3):

`categories` and `startOnTick` doesn't work well together. But you can use `labels`, `tickInterval` and `min/maxPadding` together like this to make it work:

```
var categories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return categories[this.value];
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 1,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: true,
    }
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/egQH8/29/)

Comment: @AnkitVishnoi You know how to accept an answer right?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `min/max` values and `tickmarkPlacement` as 'on'.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/egQH8/30/